# Sketch: Adding color fill between connected objects.

Tags: sketch-app

I'm trying to add a color fill between several objects that, when placed together look like the outline of a hand.

[image: hand and parts]

If this were another program I'd just use the paint bucket, but I from my research Sketch doesn't have anything like that.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Nope, there is no bucket options for vectors. What you need to do is merge all the paths so they're one outline, and then you can duplicate the inner shape. 
Here's a quick how-to:

**Step 1: Separate shapes**

[image]

**Step 2: Choose the "union" command** 
[image]

Result:

[image]

**Step 3: Use the flatten command**

[image]

Result:
[image]

**Step 4: Copy the inside path, drag it outside the combined shape, and color.** 
[image]