# How can I combine and fill these lines In Sketch?

Tags: path, sketch-app, fill

I have a few orange lines that I have drawn in sketch. I would like to combine them into one shape and use something like a "paint bucket" tool to fill the whole object with the light sand color. [image]

I saw this question ([Sketch: Adding color fill between connected objects.](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/107374/sketch-adding-color-fill-between-connected-objects?newreg=5c5ef8b4b3944c5fb9217dd55e81b319)) with a similar issue, but the solution of using Union + Flatten doesn't work for me. When I try to combine the lines with the Union tool it creates all these extra unwanted lines:

[image]

Does anyone know why it is adding all these additional lines and how I can simply combine the lines into one shape and fill it?

Answer (score 0):

high level steps

1. duplicate your linework group to create the fill layer (make sure all paths overlap)
2. to create fill layer - convert to outlines > union > flatten > ungroup > union > flatten
3. overlay your linework over the fill layer

[image]

Answer (score 0):

All those extra lines are coming from Sketch closing the paths. All those shapes are just paths which are "open" because they don't complete.

This is a good round up of what paths look like and how they act in Sketch:

- [What’s Up With Sketch’s Scissors Tool?](https://medium.com/sketch-app/what-s-up-with-sketch-s-scissors-tool-ebdf4d57276f)

  - I know the name is not directly associated to Paths, but still it's a great summary

One way you could solve this without trying to flatten and combine all your paths is:

- Group them
- Create a style that uses the appropriate fill (and border if necessary)
- Apply that style to the paths

This might not be the result you're looking for, but hopefully it's a shortcut to what you want.